# I can not attach additional network interface to an existing amazon EC2 instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, multiple-instances

I need three network interfaces in one instance for my work.By default there is one **eth0**
but I want to add **eth1** and **eth2** in an instance.

I created network interfaces using the same security rule that I used to create the EC2 instance in zone ***us-west-2a*** and my instance is also in this zone ***us-wes-2a***

**My instance type is t2.micro**

now i choose the **instance options** and choosing the instance where i want to add ,then from **actions ->networking->attach network interface** gives this error

`No available network interfaces were found for this VPC or availability zone`

Could someone guide me to resolve this issue? thanks a lot.

Comment: t2.micro only supports a total of 2 ENIs (eth0 and eth1), with a maximum of 2 IP addresses per ENI.  Larger instances are required, if you need more than this.  When you created new the ENI, you needed to create it on a subnet that is in the same VPC and same availability zone as the primary interface in the instance.  Verify that?

Comment: I am gonna move to a large instance since I need at least 3 network interface in each machine for my work . Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

> I created network interfaces using the same security rule that I used
>   to create the EC2 instance in zone us-west-2a and my instance is also
>   in this zone us-wes-2a

I think you created a security group, from the main EC2 dashboard, select Network and Security > Network Interfaces > Create network Interface.

make sure you are in the same zone as the instance you whsh to attach it to

Comment: yes i first created the network interface as u said in the same zone but I put secondary Private IP to that interface too.When I created the network interface I choose the existing security group(this security group I created after launching the instance).then I choose instance and networking and attach to the network interface but it shows the same error.